BB84 cloning games and state splitting
I have been trying to simulate cloning games for BB84 states with qiskit.
The game I am struggling with is as follows, where Alice plays against Bob and Charlie.

Alice creates a state $H^{\theta}|x \rangle $, with $x, \theta \in \{0, 1\}$.
Alice sends the state to a third party $T$. Then $T$ creates a bipartite state on registers $X$ and $Y$ by applying a channel (CPTP map) to the state it received and sends register $X$ to Bob and $Y$ to Charlie
Alice reveals $\theta$ and Bob and Charlie try to both guess $x$. They win if they both guess it.

What I am struggling when trying to implement this is step 2, because I cannot seem to find what practical operations (as in gates, measurement or whatever) can be used to optimally split the state between Bob and Charlie. What (I think) I have understood is that there is a limit to how well the state can be split, because there is an upper boundary to the winning probability, but I still not understand practically how they can do it.
I would greatly appreciate any help, resources or tips. Thank you!
